# how to update the value of a declared variable

Tags: java, android, textview

OK so I'm writing a tally counter app and I'm trying to get a button to add to a text view.

Right now I have a variable named count set equal to 0. What I want to do is make it so that whenever I press a button count is updated to count + 1, and then the new count is displayed in my text view.

This is the code I have for it right now but once I press the button once it goes to 1 and stays there.
`txtView.setText(Integer.toString(count +1));`

Comment: what is count for a variable type??

Comment: You want `++count`. `count +1` just gives you the value of count (0), plus one; the value of count does not actually change. `++count` increases the value of `count` by one, and then gives you the new value of count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `count` is a class variable:

```
txtView.setText(Integer.toString(++count));
```

Why this works: `++count` means that first the current `count` value is incremented (same as doing `count = count + 1;`), second the new value is used to change the text.

Comment: You meant `++count`, so the new value is displayed, not the old value.

Comment: Yup, should have read the question more carefully. Thank you.

Comment: Original code is to display count +1, not count. So ++count is correct. The first click shall show 1, not 0

Comment: Oh sorry, thought you were editing at the same time I was to make the `++count` change. My bad. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @NathanaelSilverman FYI: See [Syntax highlighting for code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 0):

1. count += 1 ( This should be done every click on the button, preferable in the onClick method.
2. txtView.setText(Integer.toString(count+1))
3. DONE

Comment: You don't want `+1` in the `setText()` call, since you already incremented the value.